# Line placement error in c#

Tags: c#

I could not find anything but the program includes five serious errors and some line placement faults. What are the faults? Thank you for your help

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int deger1, deger2;

        deger2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (kivir =0; kivir <2; kivir++)
        {
            if (deger1 == 56)
            Console.WriteLine(Ekle(kivir, deger1));

            deger2--;
            else deger1 = 56;

        }
    }
    static int Ekle(int deger1, int deger2)
    {
        return deger1 + deger2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0):

1. `kivir` is not declared as a variable.
2. your if statement appears to have multiple statements but is missing blocks (`{...}`).
3. deger1 is not initialized

This version can compile:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int deger1 = 0, deger2;

        deger2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int kivir =0; kivir <2; kivir++)
        {
            if (deger1 == 56)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Ekle(kivir, deger1));

                deger2--;
            }
            else
            {
                deger1 = 56;
            }

        }
    }
    static int Ekle(int deger1, int deger2)
    {
        return deger1 + deger2;
    }
}
```

However, it will close the console window before you can see the output. You need to add one more `Console.ReadLine()` before the end of the main method.

Answer (score 0):

I found one error to,there isn't a namespace.